# Explanation for background tasks on bash

Tags: bash, background-process

First, I write a simple PHP script

```
<?php
while(true)
  {
    echo 'hey'.PHP_EOL;
    sleep(1);
  }
```

Then I run it like:

```
php test.php &
```

Obviously goes into background, but keeps running and prints `hey` repeatedly.

Now run it like:

```
php test.php
```

and hit `Ctrl+Z` while it is running. It goes into background but stops running.

Why stop running? How to keep it running while it goes into background? Think of time when you run something and in the middle of it, you realize you should do something real quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> sends `SIGTSTP`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/JobControl) to the process, *suspending* it. To background it properly you need to run `bg` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! Very sad it did not come to my mind. Seems like an obvious thing :)